# How to Accept Payments via NFC in React Native and Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, nfc, payment-gateway, payment

My company has an B2B Expo managed React Native App. We want our app to act as a Point-of-Sale terminal to our users. So, we try to make them able to get payments with NFC reading their customers' contactless debit/credit cards. Is it possible to achieve with Expo managed workflow without using any payment solution SDKs, if not, is there any payment solutions offering such SDKs?

Tried to read card details with react-native-nfc-manager, but I was unable to do it. As an additional question, is there a way to achieve it by myself using this library?